# Exclude addition of certain types of files (add -X not working?)

Tags: mercurial

According to the man pages

```
hg add -X [pattern]
```

Should exclude all files matching `[pattern]` from being added. The man entry is

> -X, --exclude
>                 exclude names matching the given patterns

However, when I try to use `-X` it does not work.

```
hg add -X *.map
hg add -X "*.map"
```

both include all ".map" files in all subdirectories. Example:

> adding map_files/tRNAs/tRNAs_chr8.map
>
> adding map_files/tRNAs/tRNAs_chr9.map
>
> adding map_files/tRNAs/tRNAs_chrX.map

What gives?

Comment: For posterity, if you never want certain files/folders to be added, read Permanently ignoring unwanted files and directories from http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/file-names-and-pattern-matching.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think (because I'm too lazy to test)

`hg add -X "set:**.map"`

will play game (maybe even without set: part), just because

> The “*” character matches any string, **within a single directory**

noted in "Using patterns to identify files" section on mentioned by @VonC page

Comment: Worked without the "set". Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This pattern (Shell-style glob patterns) should work better:

```
hg add -X 'glob:*.map'
```

The page "[Chapter 7. File names and pattern matching](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/file-names-and-pattern-matching.html)" details the possible syntax.

With re pattern (regexp), it could be `hg add -X '.*\.map'` (not tested).

Comment: Any possible permutation/version of this still doesn't work, despite what all the manuals say. Will assume it is a bug and accept your answer unless some other user can show otherwise.

Comment: Why? Is it because of question visibility or what?

Comment: @TheUnfunCat just because I hope one of the Mercurial gurus (http://stackoverflow.com/tags/mercurial/topusers: R4yan or Martin Geisler) will come up with a definitive answer. Mine is not working for you.